# const parameter with inline functions

Tags: c, parameter-passing, constants, inline-functions

I have an `inline` function, that does some initialization based on the input parameters and was wondering if I should use the `const` keyword for the parameters, would that enable the compiler to do some more optimizations? For example this pseudo code:

```
inline void init(ENUM1 e1, ENUM2 e2, bool b1, bool b2, ENUM3 e3)
{
    if (b1) { … }

    switch (e2) {
      …
    }

    // And so on…
}
```

**EDIT:**

Another question regarding the same thing. When this function `init()` will get called, will the call get replaced with the whole code inside this function, or only with the parts that fit the parameters. For example, if `b1` is true, will the call get replaced with `if (b1) { … }` or only with the code in the if brackets. And same for the `switch`?

This is where I meant if adding `const` will help.

Comment: It probably won't help the compiler but it helps you because the compiler can tell you when you violated the `const` assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const`, used in `inline` code or not, is unlikely to *preclude* optimizations, but it may not necessarily allow for more.  But if it applies, there's no good reason not to tell the compiler so that it can make the best use of that information that it can.

**Update**: Since even inline code is generated at compile time, it cannot be tailored to the value of any parameter because it isn't known yet.

Comment: I don't see why the compiler couldn't look at a call `init(a, b, false, c, d);` and then skip the `if (b1) {...}` from the inlined code. In fact I would expect this to happen, perhaps at a later stage of optimization.

Comment: I supposed I should have said "...any parameter *that* isn't known yet."